# SQL Server client statistics parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can use client statistics parameters, in order to have better query performance.
I use SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use 'client statistics parameters simply because such concept does not exists. There are '[client statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833228%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)' and there are '[parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)'.

To have better query performance start with a troubleshooting methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) to identify bottlenecks and then take appropriate actions to remove the bottlenecks.